# Ajax request to php only works once per pageload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have seen a few of these questions post on here but none of them are working for me. I have a favourite button that i would like my users to press to favourite things. The ajax request is working just fine and the favourite gets stored in the database but i can only use it once then i have to refresh the page to fav/unfav the item. The code for the button is:

```
<div id="fav-icon">
    <?php
    // Function checks if user has fav'd the item.
    $isFav = favourite($user->id) ? 'un-fav' : 'fav'; 
    ?>
    <i id="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $isFav; ?>"><span class="font-12 fa fa-heart"></span></i>
</div>
```

Jquery/Ajax

```
$('.fav').click(function(e){
    var con = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      data:{
        'fav' : con
      },
      success:function(){ 
        $('#fav-icon').load(document.URL +  ' #fav-icon');
      }
    });
  });

  $('.un-fav').click(function(e){
    var con = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      data:{
        'fav' : con
      },
      success:function(){ 
        $('#fav-icon').load(document.URL +  ' #fav-icon');
      }
    });
  });
```

So this works but only once! I have tried a couple of different functions to try make this work including:

```
$('.fav').live('click', function(e) {
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong and the correct method to get my button to work multiple times?

Comment: are you changing the status from fav to unfav / unfav to fav in the ajax file?

Comment: no i am just refreshing the div with the php function to check if the item class should be fav / un-fav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(document).on()` click event

```
$(document).on('click','.fav', function(e) { 
...
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works a treat! One more problem the heart icon seems to move slightly to the right when it is clicked...I'll do some research and try figure it out. Thanks for the help!!